# Set Textarea size for all Textfields in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with tons of (10-20) fields, some of which are Textarea fields.

All of the textare fields should have a certain size (which differs from the default). I could set them all using the widget dictionary in the Meta class, but then i'd have to set them one by one, which seems unnecessary redundant.

Is there any better way to solve this?

Update:
Since it was suggested in the comments to use database normalization, I'm going to flesh out my case a little bit:
I have an model object which has the main purpose of taking in a lot of user data (i.e. an "application"). The benefit of just writing out every question to the user as one field is that I can easily create a model form for it and display and edit the data in the admin (which is good for my crm people as well).

I could create a dictonary like model for every field of the form but I'm not sure how I would go about actually using a ModelForm for creating it.

Comment: "I have a model with tons of fields, some of which are Textarea fields" google for database normalization

Comment: meant like 10 to 20 :)

Comment: yes, that's bad enough

Comment: So youre suggestion creating a second model with name and content and then using a many to many relationship?

Comment: I can't suggest anything sine you haven't posted anything

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of your data, I can only offer this approach:

```
from django import forms

textarea_fields = ['field1', 'field2']
form = YourForm()

for field_name in [f for f in form.fields.keys() if f in textarea_fields]:
    form.fields[field_name].widget = forms.Textarea()
```